# RDP server not getting proper licensing

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, licensing

I am currently setting up my Windows VMs to be connected to the licensing server, which is already configured, using the Per User CAL. Even though it seems to be running normally, when I log in to the machine using RDP, I get the warning that there is a problem with your remote desktop license and I will be disconnected within 60 minutes.

This problem only appears in my VMs, since I have another physical server connected to the licensing server configured on the same way, and the warning does not appear.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Has the RDP session host been activated online?

Comment: @GregAskew yes, the licensing server seems to be working fine and it seems to be licensed in itself

Comment: I'm referring to the RDP session host. Has that been activated online? That is separate from the license server, which only serves CALs.

Comment: Run the RD Licensing Diagnoser and tell us what it shows.

Comment: @GregAskew I don't know what the difference is,could you explain or send me a link that explains it?

Comment: @joeqwerty it does not identify any problems

Comment: @kcpf: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-activate-license-server

Comment: @GregAskew I just checked the link and it does not mention anything to be activated online, but the License Manager seems fine, although the available licenses are the same number as the total licenses even though tried to install the licenses in the clients

Comment: I'm not sure why the number of licenses are relevant. User licensing is not enforced. The RDS host needs to be activated, and have access to the license server. There should be error/warning events in the Application event log that provides more information.